# How to print from CUPS 1.5 client to CUPS 1.7 server?

Tags: cups

I have several Ubuntu machines on a network. One has a printer and all the others have an `/etc/cups/client.conf`[1](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.5/ref-client-conf.html?VERSION=1.5&Q=) file that points them to this box.

All was well until I upgraded the one that acts as a print server, which upgraded CUPS from 1.5 to 1.7.

Now my client machines don't see any of the printers. (The upgraded print machine has the printer shared, can print, is accessible over port 631 etc. - all seems well there.)

How can I get the client CUPS 1.5 machines to pass on stuff to the upgraded server as was working before?

### Workaround

The client.conf file is supposed to do this automatically for you, but I could not get it to pick up the printers from the server.

Running this on the client machine sets up a single printer

```
SERVER_IP=10.67.5.3
PRINTER=laser
sudo lpadmin -h localhost -p $PRINTER -E -v "ipp://$SERVER_IP/printers/$PRINTER"
```

I'd still like to know how to get the `client.conf` file working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUPS 1.6+ changed the way it gives access to print queues. A new package `cups-browsed` needs to be installed on the **server**, and in its config file at `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf` remove the commented line `BrowseLocalProtocols` as follows:

```
# Please remove the "#" in the beginning of the following line to make the
# local printers available to clients running CUPS 1.5.x or older.
BrowseLocalProtocols cups
```

Thanks to Brian Potkin on the cups mailing list for the hints.